# String value into array splitted by enters

Tags: php, arrays

I've a string like this:

```
$str = "
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5";
```

I want to make this into:

```
array('test1','test2','test3' ect ect)
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specifically, use the explode function using the line ending as the delimiter, then wrap that in the array_filter function to remove any stray entries from the odd line entries.

```
$arr = array_filter(explode("\n", $str));
```